# How to overlay dat in python arrays

Tags: python, arrays

I'm sorry but semi-complicated array operations like this one are still awkward for me in Python.

I have an array in Python that I created with `[0xff]*1024` and now I want to set subsequences of that to data ive calculated so lets say I've calculated `[0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04]` and want to place that within the first array at a particular position, say 10 bytes in.

So now my array should look like this:

```
[0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0xff,0xff, ... ]
```

I still want the array to be 1024 bytes long. I need to insert several of these subsequences.
So far I have:

```
a = [0xff]*1024
b = [0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04]
```

I'm not sure how to merge the two together. none of `append`, `insert` or `extend` are what I am looking for. `b` can be of arbitrary length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [list slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation):

```
a = [0xff]*1024
b = [0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04]
a[10:14] = b
```

This gets the four values between the tenth and the fourteenth values in `a` (inclusive), and changes them to the contents of `b`. There's no need to go `a[10] = b[0];a[11] = b[1]` (etc), because python already deals with this by unpacking the lists.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for slices.

```
a[10:14] = b
```

will replace `a[10]` with `b[0]`, `a[11]` with `b[1]`, `a[12]` with `b[2]`, and `a[13]` with `b[3]`.

Read the docs for more ;-)